# Functional tests with Minitest in Ruby 2.2.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

In Ruby 2.0.0, my controller tests looked something like this:

```
class CustomerControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "when not logged in" do
    order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
    get(:order, { id: order.id })
    assert_redirected_to "/customer/sign_in"
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, this no longer works in Ruby2.2. The tests still run, but all I get is this:

```
Finished in 0.000090 seconds.

0 tests, 0 passed, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips, 0 assertions
```

I've managed to get my unit tests to work by converting them to use `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`, but I don't see any way to test controller actions using MiniTest on it's own.

So my question is, is there a way to get `ActionController::Testcase` to work with Ruby2.2 in Rails 3.2, and if not, is there a way to test controller actions using `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`?

It might be worth adding that I had to install the `test-unit` gem in order to avoid this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)
```

Comment: Could you try changing the line `test "when not logged in" do` to `def test_log_in`? Basically this should be a method, where the name of method  is prefixed with `test_`

Comment: @PawełDawczak writing the tests as methods still results in zero tests and assertions

Comment: Are you sure you use Minitest? In order to use it, I have `gem "minitest-rails"` in my `Gemfile`. With this in place the tests are executed properly. Would that be the case for you?

Comment: @PawełDawczak yes that is the case for me also. The MiniTest gem itself is locked at v 4.7.5 though, could that be the problem maybe?

Comment: I think it can! The current version is >= 5.5 [link](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest)! Could you try to update to the newest version?

Comment: @PawełDawczak no I can't unfortunately, due to my rails version. The newer versions of MiniTest-Rails aren't compatible with Rails 3.2 :(

Comment: Ahhh... That explains a lot! I don't have any possible solution for you out of my head at the moment, but I'll try to investigate and I hope to get back to you ASAP (which might be a bit of difficulty as I'm at work at the moment). Stay tuned!

Comment: @PawełDawczak thanks, you've been a big help! I guess I might just have to settle for Ruby2.1 until I upgrade my Rails version